# CodeIgniter adding parenthesis to FROM clause, causing mySQL error

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-3

We recently upgraded our servers to mySQL 8.0 and started getting an error with a query that had previously been working.  This is the php code causing the error:

```
$this->db->select('tblIndicators.*,GROUP_CONCAT(tblVersionInfo.fkDatasetID) as fldDatasetIDs');
$this->db->join('tblIndicatorsDataset', 'tblIndicatorsDataset.fkIndicatorID = tblIndicators.pkIndicatorID');
$this->db->join('tblIndicatorsDatasetVersion', 'tblIndicatorsDatasetVersion.pkIndicatorsDatasetVersionID = tblIndicatorsDataset.fkIndicatorsDatasetVersionID', 'left');
$this->db->join('tblVersionInfo', 'tblIndicatorsDatasetVersion.fkDatasetVersionID = tblVersionInfo.pkVersionID', 'left');
$this->db->order_by('fldCategoryCode');
$this->db->order_by('fldOrder');
$this->db->where(array('fkIndicatorsVersionID'=>$indicatorsVersionID, 'fldDisabled'=>0));
$this->db->group_by('tblIndicators.fldIndicatorCode');

return $this->db->get($tblIndicators)->result();
```

The error returned is:

```
Query error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')
JOIN `tblIndicatorsDataset` ON `tblIndicatorsDataset`.`fkIndicatorID` = `tblIn' at line 2 - Invalid query: SELECT `tblIndicators`.*, GROUP_CONCAT(tblVersionInfo.fkDatasetID) as fldDatasetIDs
FROM ((SELECT DISTINCT(tblIndicators.pkIndicatorID) as id, tblIndicators.* FROM tblIndicatorsDataset JOIN tblIndicators ON tblIndicatorsDataset.fkIndicatorID = tblIndicators.pkIndicatorID WHERE fkIndicatorsVersionID = 32) as tblIndicators)
JOIN `tblIndicatorsDataset` ON `tblIndicatorsDataset`.`fkIndicatorID` = `tblIndicators`.`pkIndicatorID`
LEFT JOIN `tblIndicatorsDatasetVersion` ON `tblIndicatorsDatasetVersion`.`pkIndicatorsDatasetVersionID` = `tblIndicatorsDataset`.`fkIndicatorsDatasetVersionID`
LEFT JOIN `tblVersionInfo` ON `tblIndicatorsDatasetVersion`.`fkDatasetVersionID` = `tblVersionInfo`.`pkVersionID`
WHERE `fkIndicatorsVersionID` = '32'
AND `fldDisabled` = 0
GROUP BY `tblIndicators`.`fldIndicatorCode`
ORDER BY `fldCategoryCode`, `fldOrder`
```

If I update the query to remove the paretheses around the FROM clause, it runs successfully (I also disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY).  So the query looks like:

```
SET sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));

SELECT `tblIndicators`.*, GROUP_CONCAT(tblVersionInfo.fkDatasetID) as fldDatasetIDs
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT(tblIndicators.pkIndicatorID) as id, tblIndicators.* FROM tblIndicatorsDataset JOIN tblIndicators ON tblIndicatorsDataset.fkIndicatorID = tblIndicators.pkIndicatorID WHERE fkIndicatorsVersionID = 32) as tblIndicators
JOIN `tblIndicatorsDataset` ON `tblIndicatorsDataset`.`fkIndicatorID` = `tblIndicators`.`pkIndicatorID`
LEFT JOIN `tblIndicatorsDatasetVersion` ON `tblIndicatorsDatasetVersion`.`pkIndicatorsDatasetVersionID` = `tblIndicatorsDataset`.`fkIndicatorsDatasetVersionID`
LEFT JOIN `tblVersionInfo` ON `tblIndicatorsDatasetVersion`.`fkDatasetVersionID` = `tblVersionInfo`.`pkVersionID`
WHERE `fkIndicatorsVersionID` = '32'
AND `fldDisabled` = 0
GROUP BY `tblIndicators`.`fldIndicatorCode`
ORDER BY `fldCategoryCode`, `fldOrder`
```

So it seems like I need to figure out how to stop CI from adding a parenthesis around the FROM clause to get it to run.  The only thing I could figure out was maybe getting the compiled select statement and just removing them from the string, and then executing the string, but that seems like a pretty terrible solution.  This is happening on a bunch of queries, and they are from code previously written by a coworker no longer working with us, so any help on getting this fixed without having to rewrite a whole bunch of complex queries is appreciated!

Edit: Looking further into the code, $tblIndicators contains the following to create that query:

```
$tblIndicators = "(SELECT DISTINCT(tblIndicators.pkIndicatorID) as id, tblIndicators.* FROM tblIndicatorsDataset"
                    . " JOIN tblIndicators ON tblIndicatorsDataset.fkIndicatorID = tblIndicators.pkIndicatorID"
                    . " WHERE fkIndicatorsVersionID = $appVersionID) as tblIndicators";
```

Comment: every column of tblIndicators, must be in aggregation function like max,min or in the Group by, so change the query for tblIndicators.* to some thing more extebsive

Comment: That's not the issue I'm having.  The query errors because of a parenthesis around the FROM clause, not the group by issue.  I know the query without aggregation isn't accurate, but we aren't rewriting the logic in the tool right now, just trying to get around the errors from the added parenthesis.

Comment: i fail to see where it gets its subselect, i would expect a $this->db->FROM

Comment: Ah, I was looking more into the code - $tblIndicators contains code.  I will update the post

Comment: CI4 has some support for subqueries but CI3 does not. What is the reason for the subquery in `$tblIndicators`? Is it being passed in from elsewhere? In this case you would get the same outcome (I think) with just `return $this->db->get('tblIndicators')->result();` as the join and where clause are both repeated in the outer query anyway.

Comment: The query is being passed as text.  I didn't write the code originally, and there are a lot of these big nested queries.  We are looking to upgrade our very large codebase to CI4 over the next year, so maybe this will just have to be out of commission until then

Comment: The QueryBuilder isn't doing anything useful for you, so you could just replace it with a raw parameterised query.

Comment: I ended up making a view out of the subquery to get around these errors

Comment: It looks like "tblIndicators" is used both as a table name and an alias for a 'derived table'.  This is at least confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to suggest modifying the framework core for your own purposes, but this may be the best option for keeping your application fully functional in the short term. It seems unlikely there will be any more [releases of CI3](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/changelog.html).

The extra parentheses are being added by the database driver's `_from_tables()` method ([mysqli_driver.php](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/bcb17eb8ba53a85de154439d0ab8ff1bed047bc9/system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php#L536) or [pdo_mysql_driver.php](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/bcb17eb8ba53a85de154439d0ab8ff1bed047bc9/system/database/drivers/pdo/subdrivers/pdo_mysql_driver.php#L374)).

The description in the doc block says:

> Groups tables in FROM clauses if needed, so there is no confusion about operator precedence.

From the [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html#idm46441366772416):

> - `JOIN` has higher precedence than the comma operator (`,`), so the join expression `t1, t2 JOIN t3` is interpreted as `(t1, (t2 JOIN t3))`, not as `((t1, t2) JOIN t3)`. This affects statements that use an `ON` clause because that clause can refer only to columns in the operands of the join, and the precedence affects interpretation of what those operands are.

So, as long as you do not have cases of comma separated table names (or arrays of table names) being passed into either `get()` or `from()`, combined with `join()`s, you could stop the addition of the extra parentheses by deleting or commenting out the conditional block:

```php
protected function _from_tables()
{
    // if ( ! empty($this->qb_join) && count($this->qb_from) > 1)
    // {
    //     return '('.implode(', ', $this->qb_from).')';
    // }

    return implode(', ', $this->qb_from);
}
```